# Removing QAT resources from a MFC Dialog project?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017

I am been trying to resolve this issue for a while and may have stumbled over the solution. But I wanted to run it past you for confirmation if I may.

### Background

I have a `Dialog` based application and I moved from VS2015 to VS2017 RC. My application supports several language translations using **appTranslator**. I noticed that the QAT (I think that is right, Quick Access Toolbar) resources suddenly appears in appTranslator. So they were now part of my application resources. Even though I am not using a QAC in my dialog application.

### Resource Includes

I then stumbled over this in VS2017 RC in the resource editor:

[image: Resource Includes]

I noticed this bit in there:

```
#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES
#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENG)
LANGUAGE 9, 1
#include "res\MeetingScheduleAssistant.rc2"  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources
#include "afxres.rc"      // Standard components
#if !defined(_AFXDLL)
#include "afxribbon.rc"   // MFC ribbon and control bar resources
#endif
#endif
```

I don't want to blindly make changes to my application, which is why I am asking first. But I saw the latter MFC ribbon and control bar resources and wondered if this was the culprit and / or if it can be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the resolution. To remove or comment out:

```
#if !defined(_AFXDLL)
#include "afxribbon.rc"   // MFC ribbon and control bar resources
#endif
```

I notice in the new Visual Studio Wizards that it refers to the Ribbon in the project setup, but you can't remove the setting as it is disabled.